# Which variable can I deem as a constant in this integration?

Tags: integration

> I was deriving the volume of a right circular cone of height $h$ and radius $r$ and my final integration was $ V = \int_0^r 2\pi x \frac{hr - hx}{r} dx$ and the final answer is $\frac{1}{3} \pi r^2 h$.

In this integration, I know that we are only integrating the $x$ variable. Does this mean I can take out these constants? $ V = 2\pi \frac{h}{r} \int_0^r x(r-h) dx$ ? But this does not give the formula for volume of a cone

Comment: Yes. Everything is a constant except $x$.

Answer (score 2):

After taking out the constants, the volume should be $V=2\pi\frac{h}{r}\int_0^rx(r-x)dx$. You wrote in the bracket $(r-h)$ instead.

Answer (score -1):

$ V = \int_0^r 2\pi x \dfrac{hr - hx}{r} dx=2\pi\dfrac{h}{r}\int_0^rx(r-x)dx=2\pi\dfrac{h}{r}\int_0^rxr-x^2dx=2\pi\dfrac{h}{r}\left[\dfrac{x^2r}{2}-\dfrac{x^3}{3}\right]_0^r=2\pi\dfrac{h}{r}\left[\dfrac{r^3}{2}-\dfrac{r^3}{3}\right]=\dfrac{2\pi\times h×r^3}{6r}=\dfrac{1}{3} \pi r^2 h$